# Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using ADO.Net Data Providers?

Tags: ado.net, google-docs

I want use  Google Spreadsheets as data storage, but transparently via ADO.Net Data Provider. There is in some place an implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any ADO.Net provider for Google spreadsheets, but I'm not sure. However, Google have their own API called *Google Spreadsheets API* that can be used from .Net. You can find more information about this [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html).

It seems like it'll be a webservice you'll have to connect to it. But you can access it either as a list of rows or on a cell by cell basis and you can use queries to filter the data.

Edit: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/spreadsheets/)'s a sample .Net project using it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial [Google Sheets ADO.NET Provider by CData](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/gsheets/order/ado/), but I have not yet found an open source or free one.